# R ggplot and gt outputs - how can I combine these on an output image

Tags: r, ggplot2, gt

In base R I have some code that writes a table of statistics below a chart.  I would like to do a similar process with a 'ggplot' chart and a 'gt' table.  What is the best way to go about this? My attempt below using gridExtra failed.

```
# load requried packages
require(tidyverse)
require(gt)
require(gridExtra)

# make a ggplot chart
GGP   <- ggplot(dat = iris, aes( x= Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, colour = Species)) + geom_point() 

# make a dt statistics table
GT <- gt(iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(n = n(), Mean = mean(Sepal.Width), SD = sd(Sepal.Width)) 

# Plot both on one page?
grid.arrange(GGP, GT, nrow = 2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative way is to use `ggpubr` package:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)

# make a ggplot chart
GGP   <- ggplot(dat = iris, aes( x= Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, colour = Species)) + geom_point() 


# construct table with desc_statby from ggpubr package         
GT <- desc_statby(iris, measure.var = "Sepal.Width",grps = "Species")
GT <- GT[, c("Species", "length", "mean", "sd")]
GT <- ggtexttable(GT, rows = NULL, 
                        theme = ttheme("lBlack"))

grid.arrange(GGP, GT, nrow = 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To combine plots using `grid.arrange`, both of the objects need to be graphical objects or `grobs` ,  and the output from `gt` isn't. One way is to use `tableGrob()` from `gridExtra` to create the grob:

```
tab = iris %>% 
group_by(Species) %>% 
summarise(n = n(), Mean = mean(Sepal.Width), SD = sd(Sepal.Width))

grid.arrange(GGP,tableGrob(tab))
```

[image]